# Xamarin.Forms Maps Not Displaying Tiles on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have an iOS mobile app that was developed a year ago and I know **I have done the setup properly** since the Xamarin.Forms Maps were working then. I updated to the latest nuget libraries recently and I am seeing the map but without the tiles rendered. I also have entries for the info.plist permissions that cropped up in iOS 8:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Did something change recently with native maps for iOS 9?

[image: Map View]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced this issue too, also in conjunction but not exclusively with Xamarin.Forms. This behavior can be reproduced with the pre-installed Apple maps app in several cases for instance:

- if you are connected to a network that requires proxy-credentials to connect to the internet
- really bad network latency
- or reduced data-carrier network speed

At the moment it seems like there is no work-around. At least I couldn't find one suitable.

Comment: I guess I will just need to hope it works when I go to test on a real device.

Comment: May be I am late. But check your API key!

Answer (score 0):

I know answering this question is too late. But for those of you who haven't found the answers yet, could try this option, as I too had a similar issue and solved it by following the link below.

If you are using Xamarin.Forms.Maps NuGet package, some initialization code is required in each application project, after the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init method call. For iOS use the following code in your AppDelegate.cs:

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
```

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map) for more information.